# Banach Fixed Point Theorem. Measurable version.

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, reference-request, fixed-point-theorems

The Banach fixed point theorem has the following statement

> **THEOREM ( Banach contraction principle).** Let $(Y,d)$ be a complete metric space and $F:Y\to Y$ be contractive . Then $F$ has a uniqe fixed point $u$, and $F^n(y)\to u$ for each $y\in Y$.

This statement is from the excellent book [Fixed Point Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387001735) written by Andrzej Granas and James Dugundji. In this book several generalizations of this theorem are given. Several of them are to relax the hypothesis of classic contraction  to another contraction hypothesis that is weaker. For example, $d(F (x) ,F (y)) \le \phi(d (x, y))$ for all $x,y\in Y$ with $ \lim_{n \to \infty}\phi^n (d (x, y )) = 0$ ( see p. 15).

> **QUESTION** Let $ (M, d) $ be a complete metric space and $ (M\times M, \mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{M}, \mu) $  be a probability space. Suppose that $F:M\to M$ is continuous and *a.s.* contractive *i.e*.  there is a $0<\lambda<1$ such that
>   $$
> \mu\left\{
>      (x,y) :\quad d(F (x) ,F (y)) \le \lambda \cdot d(x, y)\quad
>    \right\}=1.
> $$
>   So is there a counterexample to the claim that $ F $ has a unique fixed point? If not, a reference in the form of a book that treats the subject would be well accepted answer.

**My attempt.**  Let $\delta_{(x, y)} $ the measure of Dirac concentrated in $ (x, y) $. The above question has a positive answer to the dirac measure (equivalent to the deterministic case).  I have tried to prove my assertion probability measures of the form 
$$
\mu=\dfrac{1}{1+\epsilon}\left(\delta_{(x,y)}+\epsilon\cdot \nu \right)
$$
for a $ \epsilon>0 $  small enough and any probability measure $\nu$ on $(M\times M, \mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{M})$.

Comment: What about $\mu$ being Dirac measure? I'd at least ask $\mu$ to be positive on open sets. Still, for the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ consider a contraction mapping with a fixpoint $x^*$ and change $F(x^*)$, then there is no fixpoint and $\lambda(\{x\}) = 0$. If you ask $F$ to be continuous a priori, and $\mu$ to be positive on open sets then I think your claim shall be correct.

Comment: Ok, the Lebesgue measure example does not work, other things I think are true.

Comment: @Ilya My mistake, I forgot to put the hypothesis of continuity. With hiótese the existence of continuity follows easily from other fixed point theorems. I'll add the hypothesis of the continuity issue. My interest is in the uniqueness of the fixed point.

Comment: What about avoiding Dirac measure $\mu$?

Comment: @Ilya Yes, the statement is valid for dirac measure or perturbation of the Dirac measure. I'm still thinking about it.

Comment: Is $L$ a fixed constant from $[0,1)$, or can $L$ depend upon $x,y$?

Comment: @PhoemueX, $L$ is a fixed constant. I add it now.

Comment: @PhoemueX: if $L$ can depend upon $x,y$ and is not bounded away from $1$ then even if the inequality holds everywhere, $F$ fails to have a fixpoint in general.

Comment: @Elias: an example with measures can be extended as follows. Suppose that there exists a point $x$ and a neighborhood $N$ of $(x,x)$ such that $\mu(N) = 0$. Then you can construct a contraction $F$ which has a fixpoint at $x$ and modify it on the projection of $N$ so that you loose fixpoints, yet inequality is satisfied everywhere. Perhaps, even if $F$ is continuous this is possible.

Comment: @Ilya Sorry about the absence. But I have to go now. I'll think about it.